# Get the UserId from AbpSession in SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

I can't get the `UserId` from `AbpSession` inside a class that implements `ITransientDependency`.

```
public class Chat : Hub, ITransientDependency
{
    public IAbpSession AbpSession { get; set; }

    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public Chat()
    {
        AbpSession = NullAbpSession.Instance;
        Logger = NullLogger.Instance;
    }

    private static List<MemberDto> _members = new List<MemberDto>();

    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", string.Format("User {0}: {1}", UserId(), message));
    }

    public long? UserId()
    {
        return AbpSession.UserId;
    }
}
```

Properties `UserId` and `TenantId` are still `null`.

`Chat` class is inside the "Application" layer where `AbpSession` is working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with [SignalR AspNetCore Integration](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-AspNetCore-Integration). I tried [here](https://github.com/acjh/module-zero-core-template/blob/60f888eee10677763f57e56d51430d749b721aa2/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Host/Startup/MyCommonHub.cs#L22):

```
public async Task SendMessage(string message)
{
    await Clients.All.InvokeAsync("getMessage", string.Format("User {0}: {1}", AbpSession.UserId, message));
}
```

You can now [download](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) `v3.4.1` of the template with the [Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR) preview.

## Update

You're probably not passing in the `encryptedAuthToken` as done in [SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.ts](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/b4532cef748f2b6a5537d72e56a9dd783feee4a3/angular/src/shared/helpers/SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.ts):

```js
var encryptedAuthToken = new UtilsService().getCookieValue(AppConsts.authorization.encrptedAuthTokenName);
var qs = AppConsts.authorization.encrptedAuthTokenName + "=" + encodeURIComponent(encryptedAuthToken);
```

Then pass it as a query string in the URL of your SignalR hub.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem can be related to property injection you are using:

```
public IAbpSession AbpSession { get; set; }
```

While SignalR uses DI, it does not create Chat class from DI container. That means property injection does not work. But constructor injection would work since it passes ctor parameters from DI container.

So, use constructor injection instead of property injection.

Comment: Injection is kind of working, but TenantId, UserId still null. I'm using the controller now before to call the Hub.